# How switch Bootstrap 5 columns order while its nested (without hidden duplicates)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive, bootstrap-5

The following code is supposed to display blocks for mobile and desktop view in different ways.

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 order-sm-1">TITLE</div>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 order-sm-0">IMAGE</div>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 order-sm-2 offset-sm-6">DESCRIPTION</div>
```

This code represents blocks on desktop in this way. On desktop view blocks IMAGE and TITLE will have same height.

```
--------------- ---------------
-----IMAGE----- -----TITLE-----
--------------- ---------------
--------------- ---------------
--------------- --DESCRIPTION--
--------------- ---------------
```

But I want to display these blocks (on desktop) in this way. Description block should be under title block. Both of them should represent right half of screen.

```
--------------- ---------------
--------------- -----TITLE-----
-----IMAGE----- ---------------
--------------- --DESCRIPTION--
--------------- ---------------
```

How I can do that?
Important to add that we can't use double blocks using hidden classes to switch its visibility in different views (because of SEO).

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `order` on sibling elements.

> The `order` property specifies the order of a flexible item relative to
> the rest of the flexible items inside the **same** container.

A **no JS** solution with all the columns in the same container using Flex is definitely possible utilizing `flex-basis`, but there is a drawback...

... you need a height:

*Use Dev Tools to watch them collapse below the small breakpoint.*

```css
.row {
  height: 150px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .col:nth-child(2) {
    flex: 0 100% !important;
    background: lightblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 flex-column justify-content-sm-center">
    <div class="col order-sm-2">TITLE</div>
    <div class="col order-sm-1 d-flex justify-content-sm-center align-items-sm-center">IMAGE</div>
    <div class="col order-sm-3">DESCRIPTION</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But who wants to work with heights in 2023? And don't forget:

> [Authors must not use `order` or the `*-reverse` values of
> `flex-flow/flex-direction` as a substitute for correct source ordering,
> as that can ruin the accessibility of the document.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)

**Perhaps try and use `grid` to create your layout.** No need for any ordering then:

```css
/* Create two columns of equal size. */
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

/* Let each grid-item by default span 2 columns... */
.grid-item {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  
  /* ...but only span 1 column above Bootstrap's SM breakpoint. */ 
  .grid-item {
    grid-column: span 1;
  }
  
  /* Let IMAGE start on row 1 and span 2 rows. */
  .grid-item:nth-child(2) {
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  }
}


/* COLORS */
.grid-item:nth-child(1) {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(2) {
  background: lightyellow;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(3) {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">TITLE</div>
  <div class="grid-item">IMAGE</div>
  <div class="grid-item">DESCRIPTION</div>
</div>
```

[It's also possible to use Grid in Bootstrap.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/css-grid/)